# package dependencies cannot be resolved on ubuntu software center

Tags: 14.04, software-center

I tried to install "playwithlinux" from the Ubuntu Software Center but every time I try an error pops up **"Package dependencies cannot be resolved"**. I don't know much about Ubuntu so I searched about it but I couldn't solve the problem.
My Ubuntu version is 14.04.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a Terminal window and type:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install playonlinux

This should install the newest POL without trouble.

Answer (score 0):

...and in case you faced problems with unobtainable packages (locally stored information about packages and its dependencies), you may run 
`sudo apt-get -f install` 
...that will resolve all dependencies problem.
I'm not saying you have to run that now, but at some point (maybe in your problem too), you might need to, so take this into consideration.

Comment: As far as i know  **-f install** means force-install a package. And forcing it to install means installation without checking/solving dependencies and/or architecture. E.g. force-install x32 app to x64 OS.